# show hg status for a specified repo

Tags: mercurial, status

I am not able to get the hg head or status for a given repo. is there any way to do this?

```
   ]$ hg status /home/user/test_repo/
   abort: /home/user/test_repo/ not under root
   ]$ sudo hg head /home/user/test_repo/
   abort: unknown revision '/home/user/test_repo/'!
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `-R` before path

```
hg head -R /home/user/test_repo/
```

Answer (score 2):

You got your answer with `-R` and that works, but that's more normally for scripts.  Most usually one just goes into the repositories with which one is working:

```
cd test_repo
hg status
```